# Esp32 Websocket Client Problem When Disconnected

Tags: c#, websocket, esp32, arduino-esp32

I am running a Websocket server with WebsocketSharp library on C#.
In computer and browser connections, the server is working perfectly.

However, my main goal is to connect my esp32 devices to this server and control them remotely.

I was able to successfully connect the esp32 client to the C# server; I can send and receive messages. But the OnClose method not working when connected with esp32.
To put it more clearly; the server cannot detecting that the esp32 device is disconnected.

I don't know what to do at this stage. I've tried a bunch of different client libraries for esp but only succeeded in one. But in this solution, I get an error like this.

Thanks in advance.

My C# Code:

```
using System;
using WebSocketSharp;
using WebSocketSharp.Server;
namespace web_socket
{
    public class websocser : WebSocketBehavior
    {
        protected override void OnOpen()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Device Was Connected. ID: "+ID);
            base.OnOpen();
        }
        protected override void OnClose(CloseEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Device Was Disconnected. ID: "+ID);
            base.OnClose(e);
        }
        protected override void OnMessage(MessageEventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
            base.OnMessage(e);
        }
    }
}
```

My ESP Code:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WebSocketsClient.h>
 
WebSocketsClient webSocket;
 
const char *ssid     = "#####";
const char *password = "#####";
 
unsigned long messageInterval = 5000;
bool connected = false;
 
#define DEBUG_SERIAL Serial
 
void hexdump(const void *mem, uint32_t len, uint8_t cols = 16) {
    const uint8_t* src = (const uint8_t*) mem;
    DEBUG_SERIAL.printf("\n[HEXDUMP] Address: 0x%08X len: 0x%X (%d)", (ptrdiff_t)src, len, len);
    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if(i % cols == 0) {
            DEBUG_SERIAL.printf("\n[0x%08X] 0x%08X: ", (ptrdiff_t)src, i);
        }
        DEBUG_SERIAL.printf("%02X ", *src);
        src++;
    }
    DEBUG_SERIAL.printf("\n");
}
 
void webSocketEvent(WStype_t type, uint8_t * payload, size_t length) {
 
    switch(type) {
        case WStype_DISCONNECTED:
            DEBUG_SERIAL.printf("[WSc] Disconnected!\n");
            connected = false;
            break;
        case WStype_CONNECTED: {
            DEBUG_SERIAL.printf("[WSc] Connected to url: %s\n", payload);
            connected = true;
 
            // send message to server when Connected
            DEBUG_SERIAL.println("[WSc] SENT: Connected");
            // webSocket.sendTXT("Connected");
        }
            break;
        case WStype_TEXT:
            DEBUG_SERIAL.printf("[WSc] RESPONSE: %s\n", payload);
            break;
        case WStype_BIN:
            DEBUG_SERIAL.printf("[WSc] get binary length: %u\n", length);
            hexdump(payload, length);
            break;
        case WStype_PING:
            // pong will be send automatically
            DEBUG_SERIAL.printf("[WSc] get ping\n");
            break;
        case WStype_PONG:
            // answer to a ping we send
            DEBUG_SERIAL.printf("[WSc] get pong\n");
            break;
    case WStype_ERROR:
    case WStype_FRAGMENT_TEXT_START:
    case WStype_FRAGMENT_BIN_START:
    case WStype_FRAGMENT:
    case WStype_FRAGMENT_FIN:
        break;
    }
}
 
void setup() {
    DEBUG_SERIAL.begin(115200);
 
//  DEBUG_SERIAL.setDebugOutput(true);
 
    DEBUG_SERIAL.println();
    DEBUG_SERIAL.println();
    DEBUG_SERIAL.println();
 
    for(uint8_t t = 4; t > 0; t--) {
        DEBUG_SERIAL.printf("[SETUP] BOOT WAIT %d...\n", t);
        DEBUG_SERIAL.flush();
        delay(1000);
    }
 
    WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
 
    while ( WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED ) {
      delay ( 500 );
      DEBUG_SERIAL.print ( "." );
    }
    DEBUG_SERIAL.print("Local IP: "); DEBUG_SERIAL.println(WiFi.localIP());
    // server address, port and URL
    webSocket.begin("192.168.1.34", 1005, "/ExEsp");
 
    // event handler
    webSocket.onEvent(webSocketEvent);
}
 
unsigned long lastUpdate = millis();
 
 
void loop() {
    webSocket.loop();
    // if (connected && lastUpdate+messageInterval<millis()){
    //     DEBUG_SERIAL.println("[WSc] SENT: Simple js client message!!");
    //     webSocket.sendTXT("Simple js client message!!");
    //     lastUpdate = millis();
    // }
}
```

Comment: Is server application terminating before close event occurs?

Comment: The way it's written, your ESP32 never disconnects. Or are you switching it off to force a disconnect?

Comment: @PMF When I turn off the power of the ESP device, the websocket does not detect that this device is turned off.

Comment: I think that's normal (or it will take a _very_ long time), because TCP is just not built for that. You'll only get an error back if you actually send a packet. The easiest way around this is to regularly send a "keep alive" packet. That will tell you when the remote end is gone.

Comment: @PMF Thanks for the response. I thought that too, but can it cause problems with this program when there are too many devices? Also I don't know how to do this with websocketsharp.

Comment: I can't help you with that library, as I don't know it. But no, a server should be able to handle many similar connections at a time. Particularly if these are slow devices with little data volumes.